# Dpkg-reconfigure -a: `ia32-libs-multiarch' is not installed

Tags: dpkg, multiarch

Ubuntu 12.04, couple days old. Multiarch is installed. Checked in Synaptics and Software Center.. reinstalled a couple times, from both places. It still gives me these errors:

> ```
> $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
> Package `ia32-libs-multiarch' is not installed and no info is available.
> Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
> and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
> /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: ia32-libs-multiarch is not installed
>
> $ sudo dpkg --info ia32-libs-multiarch
> dpkg-deb: error: failed to read archive `ia32-libs-multiarch': No such file or directory
>
> $ dpkg -l ia32-libs-multiarch
> Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
> | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
> |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
> ||/ Name           Version        Description
> +++-==============-==============-============================================ 
> un  ia32-libs-mult <none>         (no description available)
>
> $ dpkg -l *multiarch*
> Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
> | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
> |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
> ||/ Name           Version        Description
> +++-==============-==============-============================================
> un  ia32-libs-mult <none>         (no description available)
> un  libgl1-mesa-gl <none>         (no description available)
> ii  multiarch-supp 2.15-0ubuntu10 Transitional package to ensure multiarch com
> un  pango1.0-multi <none>         (no description available)
> un  xserver-xorg-c <none>         (no description available)
> ```

**--**

I installed Ia32 shared libraries - transitional package and multiarch-support (multiarch-supprt:i386 is not installable as it wants to remove the other one), and tried unpacking, configuring, and installing: still says not there.

Comment: you could try purging and reinstalling multiarch-support

Comment: I actually just installed multiarch-support after getting this error, still same issue and still told that ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 is installed.
`$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.`
Is there some kind of.. re-write the dpkg list so it stops looking for things command?

Comment: that's what purge+apt-get autoremove and re-install is supposed to accomplish...if it doesn't you probably have something already installed that "depends" on it or it's set to manually installed.  -f reinstall might help

Comment: All of the above.. same dpkg-reconfigure issue.

Comment: When trying apt-get purge multiarch support, I receive a big bunch of unmet dependencies and "is to be installed".. although I believe a lot of these are installed.